# IE7 does not center inline input inside absolutely positioned form

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7

The page experiences a peculiar failure when running in IE7 (strictly IE8 in Compatibility View). A similar error occurs in IE6 when I use XP mode (along with a few other errors), but I'm not too worried about IE6 compatibility.

Namely, the input box is left-aligned when it should be centred as an inline element. Relevant CSS:

```css
form#prompt {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
}

input#password { 
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 398px;
    display: inline; 
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```html
<form id="prompt">
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
</form>
```

Now the really peculiar thing is that when you trigger the submit listener on the form, which returns false and initializes the callback `$('#prompt_output').text(' ').css('opacity',0).text('Access granted. Loading...').fadeTo(200,1);`, everything works. The input rights itself. In fact, even when the callback is just `$('#prompt_output').text(' ')`, it works. Just selecting the element `$('#prompt_output');` doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that link requires a password

Comment: the acceptable password is `password`, but you can enter anything to trigger the form submit listener for the purposes of my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without drastically changing the CSS/markup I think this solves the problem in ie7 (not tested in ie6).

Try wrapping the label around the input - I have no idea why it works and I have only tested in ie7, ie8 and firefox but it seems to do the trick.

```
<label for="password" class="instruction">
    Access restricted: enter password
   <br>
   <input name="password" id="password" type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: Although it's almost certainly not standard to have an `input` tag as a child of `label`, this fix seems to work in IE7 and IE6.

Comment: Actually I think it's perfectly valid to wrap the input. Not sure about the <br /> though.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your page through [an emulator](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php) and this is obviously an IE7 and previous versions problem. It works on FF and on IE8. But I think you already know that.

I suggest you do a quick & dirty fix - by adding onload to the `<body>` that will run `$('#prompt_output').text(' ')`, just to set things straight. 
When you have the time to explore IE6/7 bugs, I suggest you try and change the layout, since I think IE doesn't know how to interpret your CSS properly.